# azure logic app, visual studio, open existing logic app from portal?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-logic-apps

can you import or open existing logic apps from the azure portal in Visual Studio 2015? I don't want to recreate them all! I've looked at the code view in the azure portal and it looks like I can copy that to Visual Studio but that is throwing up all sorts of errors. Surely there must be a way? TIA

Comment: Please provide some code what you've tried so far. Also make it easier for others to give you adequate answers by posting the errors you get. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I was mainly asking for generic import/open functionality and if anyone knew how. 

The copy/paste of the portal code view doesn't work, even with the simplest of logic apps, so some manual editing must be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [cloudexplorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MicrosoftCloudExplorer.CloudExplorerforVisualStudio2015) for VS2015 you should be able to open existing logicapps in VS -> LogicApps Editor

Pre-Req
Install LogicApps VS extension available [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VinaySinghMSFT.AzureLogicAppsToolsforVisualStudio)
**Example snapshot below**[image]

*Latest update (v2.7) for the logic apps extension has the "**Download**" feature to get the codeview locally.*

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, still no way to import existing logic apps code view into Visual Studio 2015 though, will keep looking...

Comment: No there is no feature like that. You can always ask or vote for the features https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps

Comment: Please mark the answer as helpful, as this is the only solution currently available.